# Rails GeoKit to Exclude a Result Based on ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, geokit

I have the following Code

```
@venue = Venue.friendly.find(params[:id])
@venues_nearby = Venue.within(100, :origin => [@venue.lat, @venue.lng]).where(:id != @venue.id)
```

I want to exclude the Record `@venue.id`

Is there any way to chain the same with the `.within` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"within" returns a scope so you can do this using normal arel where:

> Location.within(3.9, origin: @loc_a).where("id != #{@loc_e.id}")

If you want a nicer syntax like you had you could use the squeel gem to get:

> Location.within(3.9, origin: @loc_a).where{ id != @loc_e.id }

Comment: any particular reason i need to add the where clause in quotes?